# How to pass dynamic parameter in neo4j Cypher Query with like operator

Tags: java, regex, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to pass parameter in neo4j Cypher Query with like operator from Spring data neo4j. Please tell me its right way to pass parameter with like operate .. please help me.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put(queryAfterSubstutuet(collabVo),
                    groupIdAfterSubstituet(collabVo));
             map.put("display_name",input); 
Result<Map<String, Object>> result = neoOperation.query(
                    collabVo.getSearchQuery(), map);
```

Its my getSearchQuery

```
MATCH (n:OrganizationUnit {id:{class}})-[r:PART]-(c)-[r1:STUDENTROLE]-(f) where f.firstName =~"{display_name}.*"  RETURN f
```

But it's throwing error

```
 Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
[STDERR] {display_name}.*
[STDERR]    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
[STDERR]    at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Pattern.java:3104)
[STDERR]    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2101)
[STDERR]    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964)
[STDERR]    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1665)
[STDERR]    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1337)
[STDERR]    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1022)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your query to look like:

```
MATCH (n:OrganizationUnit {id:{class}})-[r:PART]-(c)-[r1:STUDENTROLE]-(f) 
where f.firstName =~{display_name} RETURN f
```

and add to your parameters

```
map.put("display_name",input);
```

where input contains the full pattern (like input="nameToMatch.*"), that should work.

Comment: Thank u so much for saving me ..!!^..^